# ANT replace string part in variable using a property

Tags: replace, ant

hy guys, 
i'm trying to replace a part of string inside a property like below

```
<property file="build-local.properties" /> <-- 


<propertyregex property="destProperty" input="${sourceProperty}" regexp="${whatMatch}" replace="" global="true" />
```

in order to replace content of property **${sourceProperty}** matching string **${whatMatch}** replacing with none (in this case) and finally assign result to property **${destProperty}**

Currently i'm getting **${whatMatch}** from build-local.properties file and **${sourceProperty}** as terminal arguments

But it doesn't work.

Where i'm wrong ??

**Important notes**

Changing

```
<propertyregex property="destProperty" input="${sourceProperty}" regexp="${whatMatch}" replace="" global="true" />
```

from above to

```
<propertyregex property="destProperty" input="${sourceProperty}" regexp="HARDCODED_STRING" replace="" global="true" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the values of `${sourceProperty}` and `${whatMatch}`?

Answer (score 0):

we solved using the following format:

```
<propertyregex property="normalizedAppVersion" input="${appVersion}" regexp="${projectPrefix}\." replace="" casesensitive="false" />
```

**IMPORTANTS NOTES**

If you're trying to replace a text that contains a ".", you can have some problem specifying dot inside property definition. So i just using the "."

```
   # instead "MYPACKAGE." 
   projectPrefix="MYPACKAGE." 
   regexp="${projectPrefix}\."
```

directly in the regexp attribute value. I don't know why but if not doesn't work for me.

Thanks BTW